# How to get the value of Keras variable

Tags: keras

I want to print the shape of the input.

However, there is an error.

How to do that?

Thank you very much.

```
from keras.engine.topology import Layer
import keras.backend as K
import numpy as np

class SpatialPyramidPooling(Layer):

def __init__(self, pool_list, **kwargs):
    self.dim_ordering = K.image_dim_ordering()
    assert self.dim_ordering in {'tf', 'th'}, 'dim_ordering must be in {tf, th}'
    self.pool_list = pool_list
    self.num_outputs_per_channel = sum([i * i for i in pool_list])
    super(SpatialPyramidPooling, self).__init__(**kwargs)

def call(self, x, mask=None):
    input_shape = K.shape(x)
    print(input_shape))#<--------------------cannot print
    print(K.eval(input_shape))
    return K.variable(value=np.random.random((3,4)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get an *idea* of the shape by just `print(x)` or `K.int_shape(x)` which will print a tensor with some question marks or `None` in it. You **can't** print the exact shape by using eval or any other means while you are constructing the computation graph. You only know that at training or prediction time (ie when the computation is run).